# Resize desktop to fit HDTV output

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, resolution, hdmi

I'm new to Linux and trying to learn to love it.  At the moment, I'm using a mid-spec laptop that I connect to a 37" HDTV via an HDMI cable.  This setup suits me really well and works (almost) seamlessly in Windows.

The laptop includes an NVIDIA GT540M graphics card and some sort of Intel graphics technology as well - not too sure about the Intel specs (and don't really think I should have to be).

After hours of research and much wasted time, I have the NVIDIA 340.x driver installed and working fine.  I have Ubuntu resolution settings at 1920x1080 as should be but have lost the outside edges of my desktop to beyond the screen width.  Some call this "overscan", Wikipedia disagrees.

The NVidia X Server app seems to do absolutely nothing.  I prefer not to invest too much more time in this venture if at all possible (takes seconds and almost no brain power with Windows).

My question is, how can I fit my laptop's output to my TV at the 1920x1080 resolution using the X Server application?